# Android: dynamically create matrix of editText based on user input?

Tags: android, android-layout, matrix

I'm new to android development. I've noticed some similar questions but none of them really answered my question well enough that I could figure it out, or else they relied upon depreciated functions.

So far, I've created my main class. I want to open to a screen where the user inputs two numbers for the row and column length of a matrix they want to reduce

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public int numberOfRows;
public int numberOfColumns;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void setRows(View v3) {
    EditText editTextRow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    if ("".equals(editTextRow.getText())) {
    }
    else {
        numberOfRows = Integer.parseInt(editTextRow.getText().toString());
    }
}

public void setColumns(View v2) {
    EditText editTextCol = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
   if ("".equals(editTextCol.getText())) {
        numberOfRows = Integer.parseInt(editTextCol.getText().toString());
    }
}

public void reduce(View view){
    if(numberOfRows != 0 && numberOfColumns != 0) {
    }
    else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ReduceMatrix.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("rows", numberOfRows);
        bundle.putInt("cols", numberOfColumns);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

 }
```

I'm having trouble coming up with the next activity, where I want to dynamically create a matrix of editText...

```
public class ReduceMatrix extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reduce_matrix);


    Intent passedIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = passedIntent.getExtras();

    int rowNum = extras.getInt("rows");
    int colNum = extras.getInt("cols");
```

Could anyone explain how to go about doing this? I was thinking some sort of for loop, but I have a really hard time with the android layout. Should I be using tableLayout? or gridview? Whenever I have something like

```
    layout = new LinearLayout(this);
```

It tells me that my qualifier must be in an expression?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it programmatically. Here's my solution :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent passedIntent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = passedIntent.getExtras();

    EditText[][] editTexts = new EditText[rowNum][colNum];

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);

    //define how many rows and columns to be used in the layout
    gridLayout.setRowCount(rowNum);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(colNum);

    for (int i = 0; i < rowNum; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colNum; j++) {
            editTexts[i][j] = new EditText(this);
            setPos(editTexts[i][j], i, j);
            gridLayout.addView(editTexts[i][j]);
        }
    }
    setContentView(gridLayout);
}

//putting the edit text according to row and column index
private void setPos(EditText editText, int row, int column) {
    GridLayout.LayoutParams param =new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    param.width = 100;
    param.height = 100;
    param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    param.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(row);
    param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(column);
    editText.setLayoutParams(param);
}
```

This will enable you to add EditText(s) dynamically.

Comment: Thank you. What should my xml file look like? Should i have an empty gridLayout? Currently this compiles, but nothing is visible when the app is run

Comment: @JVandeve you don't need an xml file, because what this code does is creating the layout programmatically. So, you don't need to make an xml file for the layout. Then, can you tell me more about `nothing is visible`? Do you mean no activity shown (looks like app is not launched) ? If yes, then you need to add an intent filter to your activity at `AndroidManifest.xml` file.